# Applying different color to the sentence

Tags: html, css

I have sentence in html.I want to set a particular color to some text on the same line next to each other [closed].I try it with "p style=color:red" tag.But it shows the color change with next line.I want to view that within the same line.Please Help me to do that successfully...

Thank you

```
<table>
<tr>        
<td colspan="2">Your registration has been accepted.Site has send a 
<p style=color:red>Verification Link </p>on your Email ID.Please click on the hyperlink in the Confirmation Email to confirm your Email ID.Your registration have been in effect upon receiving your confirmation reply.</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Result:

> Your registration has been accepted.Site has send a
>
> Verification Link
>
> on your Email ID.Please click on the hyperlink in the Confirmation Email to confirm your Email ID.Your registration have been in effect upon receiving your confirmation reply.

I want to show that as one line

> Your registration has been accepted.Site has send a Verification Link on your Email ID.Please click on the hyperlink in the Confirmation Email to confirm your Email ID.Your registration have been in effect upon receiving your confirmation reply.

Comment: You are missing quotes around `color:red`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: And in some browsers it would still work without quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `" "` around your styling expression.
In addition to that if you want to "view that within the same line" use `span`:

```
<span style="color:red;">Verification Link</span>
```

but still it is not the best way to do this. You should definitely read about **CSS**.

**CSS way to do this, the right one:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .verification { color: red; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Only the <span class="verification">verification class</span> example.</p>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to use

```
<span style="color:red;">Verification Link</span>
```

instead of the p-Tag & I would deny all inline css btw.

Comment: This is probably the correct answer. You can't use `p` because it's a block element hence they won't sit next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

You should have quotation marks around your styles. You should also end each style with a semicolon (in this case you just have one, so just end it with one).

```
<span style="color: red;">Verification Link</span>
```